# vkCreatePipeline fails and validation layer segment faults

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to draw something to the HTC Vive with Vulkan.

I had validation layer enabled and program gave me segment fault inside `vkCreateGraphicsPipeline`. The segment fault happened in `VkLayer_core_validation.dll`. If that wasn't odd enough the function that segment fault happened in was `vkEmurateInstanceExtensions`. So, I tested without validation layer and then `vkCreateGraphicsPipeline` failed with `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT` as a result.

I have now read the pipeline section of the tutorial I am following several times and I have not found anything wrong. Also I tried older version of the Vulkan SDK but the only difference is that that segment fault happens in `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` inside of `vkCreateGraphicsPipeline`.

```
static int loadShader(VrDevice *device,VkShaderModule *module,char *filename){
    // load the shader
         .
         .
         .
    // Create the VkShaderModule
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shadermodule;
    shadermodule.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    shadermodule.flags=0;
    shadermodule.pNext=NULL;
    shadermodule.codeSize=buffersize;
    shadermodule.pCode=(const uint32_t *)buffer;
    VkResult result=vkCreateShaderModule(device->logicaldevice,&shadermodule,NULL,module);

    // Check for vulkan error and free allocated memory before exiting
    delete[] buffer;
    if(result==VK_SUCCESS) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int renderingInit(VrDevice *device,char *appname){
     .
     .
     .

    VkApplicationInfo appinfo;
    appinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appinfo.pNext=NULL;
    appinfo.apiVersion=VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    appinfo.pApplicationName=appname;
    appinfo.applicationVersion=1;
    appinfo.pEngineName=appname;
    appinfo.engineVersion=1;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceinfo;
    instanceinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceinfo.pNext=NULL;
    instanceinfo.flags=0;
    instanceinfo.pApplicationInfo=&appinfo;
    instanceinfo.enabledExtensionCount=numextension;
    instanceinfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames=extensions;
    instanceinfo.enabledLayerCount=layercount;
    instanceinfo.ppEnabledLayerNames=debuglayers;

    if(vkCreateInstance(&instanceinfo,NULL,&device->instance)!=VK_SUCCESS) return 0;
     .
     .
     .

    // Graphics card related matters
    uint32_t devicecount=1;
    result=vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(device->instance,&devicecount,&device->physicaldevice);
    if(result==VK_SUCCESS || result==VK_INCOMPLETE){       
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(device->physicaldevice,&device->physicaldeviceprop);
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(device->physicaldevice,&device->physicaldevicememprop);
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(device->physicaldevice,&device->physicaldevicefeatures);
    }
    else return 0

    uint32_t queuecount;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device->physicaldevice,&queuecount,NULL);
    if(queuecount>0){
        VkQueueFamilyProperties *queues=new VkQueueFamilyProperties[queuecount];
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device->physicaldevice,&queuecount,queues);
        uint32_t queue;
        for(queue=0;queue<queuecount;queue++){
            if(queues[queue].queueFlags&VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) break;
        }

        delete[] queues;

        device->queuefamily=queue;

    }
    else return 0;
     .
     .
     .                  
    // Make logical device
    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueinfo;
    queueinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    queueinfo.pNext=NULL;
    queueinfo.flags=0;
    queueinfo.queueCount=1;
    queueinfo.queueFamilyIndex=device->queuefamily;
    float priority=1.0f;
    queueinfo.pQueuePriorities=&priority;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo createinfo;
    createinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    createinfo.pNext=NULL;
    createinfo.flags=0;
    createinfo.pQueueCreateInfos=&queueinfo;
    createinfo.queueCreateInfoCount=1;
    createinfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames=extensions;
    createinfo.enabledExtensionCount=numextensions;
    createinfo.ppEnabledLayerNames=NULL;
    createinfo.enabledLayerCount=0;
    createinfo.pEnabledFeatures=&device->physicaldevicefeatures;

    if(vkCreateDevice(device->physicaldevice,&createinfo,NULL,&device->logicaldevice)!=VK_SUCCESS) return 0;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(device->logicaldevice,device->queuefamily,0,&device->queue);

    // Create the frame image for the Vive

     .
     .
     .      

    // Create renderpass
    VkAttachmentDescription colorattachment;
    colorattachment.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB;
    colorattachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    colorattachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    colorattachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    colorattachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorattachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorattachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    colorattachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference attachreferences;
    attachreferences.attachment=0;
    attachreferences.layout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpass;
    subpass.flags=0;
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint=VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.inputAttachmentCount=0;
    subpass.pInputAttachments=NULL;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount=1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments=&attachreferences;
    subpass.pResolveAttachments=0;
    subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment=0;
    subpass.preserveAttachmentCount=0;
    subpass.pPreserveAttachments=0;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderpassinfo;
    renderpassinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderpassinfo.pNext=NULL;
    renderpassinfo.flags=0;
    renderpassinfo.attachmentCount=1;
    renderpassinfo.pAttachments=&colorattachment;
    renderpassinfo.subpassCount=1;
    renderpassinfo.pSubpasses=&subpass;
    renderpassinfo.dependencyCount=0;
    renderpassinfo.pDependencies=NULL;

    if(vkCreateRenderPass(device->logicaldevice,&renderpassinfo,NULL,&device->renderpass)!=VK_SUCCESS) return 0;

    //** Load shaders and handle pipeline creation **//

    // Pipeline layout
    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo createinfo;
    createinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    createinfo.pNext=NULL;
    createinfo.flags=0;
    createinfo.setLayoutCount=0;
    createinfo.pSetLayouts=NULL;
    createinfo.pushConstantRangeCount=0;
    createinfo.pPushConstantRanges=NULL;
    if(vkCreatePipelineLayout(device->logicaldevice,&createinfo,NULL,&device->pipelinelayout)!=VK_SUCCESS) return 0;


    // Shader modules.
    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderstages[2];
    if(loadShader(device,&shaderstages[0].module,VERTEX_SHADER_NAME)==0 && loadShader(device,&shaderstages[1].module,FRAGMENT_SHADER_NAME)==0) return 0;

    shaderstages[0].sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    shaderstages[0].pNext=NULL;
    shaderstages[0].flags=0;
    shaderstages[0].stage=VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    shaderstages[0].pSpecializationInfo=NULL;
    shaderstages[0].pName="main";
    shaderstages[1].sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    shaderstages[1].pNext=NULL;
    shaderstages[1].flags=0;
    shaderstages[1].stage=VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    shaderstages[1].pSpecializationInfo=NULL;
    shaderstages[1].pName="main";

    // Descripte the vertex input to pipeline.
    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexinfo;
    vertexinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexinfo.pNext=NULL;
    vertexinfo.flags=0;
    vertexinfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions=NULL;
    vertexinfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount=0;
    vertexinfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions=NULL;
    vertexinfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount=0;

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputassembly;
    inputassembly.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputassembly.pNext=NULL;
    inputassembly.flags=0;
    inputassembly.topology=VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputassembly.primitiveRestartEnable=VK_FALSE;

    // Viewport decide what reqion of framebuffer is used.
    VkViewport viewport = {0.0f,0.0f,(float)device->renderwidth,(float)device->renderheight,0.0f,1.0f};
    // Scissors decide how much pippeline covers the window (how much info goes to rasterizing).
    VkRect2D scissor = {0,0,device->renderwidth,device->renderheight};

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportstate;
    viewportstate.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportstate.pNext=NULL;
    viewportstate.flags=0;
    viewportstate.pScissors=&scissor;
    viewportstate.scissorCount=1;
    viewportstate.pViewports=&viewport;
    viewportstate.viewportCount=1;

    // Rasterization infomration
    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterization;
    rasterization.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterization.pNext=NULL;
    rasterization.flags=0;
    rasterization.depthClampEnable=VK_FALSE;
    rasterization.rasterizerDiscardEnable=VK_FALSE;
    rasterization.polygonMode=VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterization.cullMode=VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterization.frontFace=VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterization.depthBiasEnable=VK_FALSE;
    rasterization.depthBiasConstantFactor=0.0f;
    rasterization.depthBiasClamp=0.0f;
    rasterization.lineWidth=1.0f;

    // Multisampling
    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling;
    multisampling.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.pNext=NULL;
    multisampling.flags=0;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples=VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable=VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.minSampleShading=0.0f;
    multisampling.pSampleMask=NULL;
    multisampling.alphaToCoverageEnable=VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.alphaToOneEnable=VK_FALSE;

    // Color blending
    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorblendattachment;
    colorblendattachment.colorWriteMask=VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
    colorblendattachment.blendEnable=VK_FALSE;
    colorblendattachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor=VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    colorblendattachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor=VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    colorblendattachment.colorBlendOp=VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    colorblendattachment.srcColorBlendFactor=VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    colorblendattachment.dstColorBlendFactor=VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    colorblendattachment.alphaBlendOp=VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorblend;
    colorblend.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorblend.pNext=NULL;
    colorblend.flags=0;
    colorblend.logicOpEnable=VK_FALSE;
    colorblend.logicOp=VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
    colorblend.attachmentCount=1;
    colorblend.pAttachments=&colorblendattachment;
    colorblend.blendConstants[0]=0;
    colorblend.blendConstants[1]=0;
    colorblend.blendConstants[2]=0;
    colorblend.blendConstants[3]=0;

    // If tuo want to change viewport, line width, blend constants you have to change it in this data type.
    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicstateinfo;
    dynamicstateinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicstateinfo.pNext=NULL;
    dynamicstateinfo.flags=0;
    dynamicstateinfo.dynamicStateCount=0;
    dynamicstateinfo.pDynamicStates=NULL;

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineinfo;
    pipelineinfo.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineinfo.pNext=NULL;
    pipelineinfo.flags=0;
    pipelineinfo.stageCount=2;
    pipelineinfo.pStages=shaderstages;
    pipelineinfo.pVertexInputState=&vertexinfo;
    pipelineinfo.pInputAssemblyState=&inputassembly;
    pipelineinfo.pViewportState=&viewportstate;
    pipelineinfo.pRasterizationState=&rasterization;
    pipelineinfo.pMultisampleState=&multisampling;
    pipelineinfo.pDepthStencilState=NULL;
    pipelineinfo.pColorBlendState=&colorblend;
    pipelineinfo.pDynamicState=&dynamicstateinfo;
    pipelineinfo.layout=device->pipelinelayout;
    pipelineinfo.renderPass=device->renderpass;
    pipelineinfo.subpass=0;
    pipelineinfo.basePipelineHandle=VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    pipelineinfo.basePipelineIndex=0;

    // ** TODO: SEGMENT FAULT WHILE DEBUG LAYER IS ON! ** //
    if((result=vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device->logicaldevice,VK_NULL_HANDLE,1,&pipelineinfo,NULL,&device->pipeline))!=VK_SUCCESS) return 0;

    // Destroy shaders after pipeline creation
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device->logicaldevice,shaderstages[0].module,NULL);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device->logicaldevice,shaderstages[1].module,NULL);
}
```

EDIT 1: Changed debug layer to validation layer.

Additional info:
Vulkan SDK version 1.0.54.0

Comment: A few more details would be helpful: What version of the SDK are you using, what version of the Vulkan runtime, does the output of `vulkaninfo` show anything fishy, are your graphics drivers current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the layers (and potentially in the driver — it does crash my AMD at the least).
Instead of uninitialized value for `pipelineinfo.pTessellationState` (valid, but apparently crashes) try `NULL`.

You have other errors that should be caught by layers if compiled in debug mode:

- uninitialized `colorattachment.flags` (probably should be `0`)
- `dynamicstateinfo.dynamicStateCount` **must** not be `0` (if you want to disable dynamic states completelly use `pipelineinfo.pDynamicState=NULL` instead)
- one shader module won't be loaded due to the `&&` short-circuiting (I think you meant to use `||` instead)

Please enable your validation layers (`"VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"`) + reporting **and** verify they work as intended. Compile and test your program in compilers debug mode (it will help you by filling uninitialized values by filling them with more detectable pattern). For me those three were cought and properly reported before the crash.

I am in middle of fixing the first, and hopefully it will land in next release of layers.

Comment: Thank it started to work when `&&` "brain fart" was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you are leaving a pointer unassigned and containing an invalid non-NULL pointer value.  Although it looks like you've tried to fill in every struct member field in the code, there's a chance one got overlooked.  It may be worth trying to clear the entire struct before running the code to set the members.

Hopefully your use of "debug layers" means enabling the standard validation layer.  The standard validation layer is a meta-layer that enables several validation-related layers, including "parameter checking" and "core validation".

The parameter checking layer will often report an error message if it finds a NULL pointer where there should be a valid pointer.  That's why I suggested clearing your structs.  This could enable this layer to produce a meaningful message.

The core_validation layer assumes that parameter checking "passed" and therefore won't always test pointers for NULL before dereferencing.  And it can't avoid dereferencing bad non-NULL pointers.  The intent is that the parameter checking layer will successfully report an error message that is useful, even though the app might crash later in core validation.  The programmer should then address the error reported by parameter checking which would then permit the core validation to do its job.

So, bottom line, I'd suggest clearing all your structs to zero before filling them in.  Make sure you are using the standard validation meta-layer which includes parameter checking.  Then watch for validation error messages.

If all that fails, then you might want to catch the seg fault in the validation layers to get a clue about what data structure is causing the fault.  It looks like you may have a symbol mismatch between the layer code and your symbol files.  It may be worth trying to resolve that or build your own layers so that you have accurate symbols.

Comment: It is potentially bad advice to clear a struct beforehand, With uninitialized values it at least fails hard (=good thing) sometimes (especially in debug mode) when I forget to set a value. And in C++ there is probably a better approach to handle this aspect altogether.

Comment: After compiling validation layer I know that the segment fault happens in `validate_pipeline_shader_stage`. Line 1290 `if (!module->has_valid_spirv) return false;`. `module` is null for fragment shader.